# Symmetrization map

Tags: lie-algebras, algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra, define a symmetrization map $S\mathfrak{g} \to U\mathfrak{g}$ by $x_1 .. x_n \to \frac{1}{n!} \sum x_{\sigma(1)} .. x_{\sigma(n)}$ (here $x_j$ are elements of degree 1). As far as I know, it is an isomorphism. How to write down the inverse map?

Comment: Yes, it is a linear isomorphism.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde
Is it possible to write down the inverse?

Comment: If $S\mathfrak{g}$ denotes the symmetric algebra then your map is the injection, i.e. it doesn't do anything. Example if $n=2$,  $x_1 x_2 = x_2 x_1 $ in $S\mathfrak{g}$ and these are also equal to $\frac{1}{2}(x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_1)$. In fact $S\mathfrak{g}$ is defined as a quotient of $U\mathfrak{g}$. There is a projection map and your injection is a right inverse of that projection.